# python turtle won't change color

Tags: python

I am a beginner to python and I am meant to be creating a piece of code that draws any angle, but the angle should turn red if the angle is 90 degrees. In my situation though, it won't change color.

```
from turtle import *
Angle = int(input('How many degrees? '))
if Angle == '90':
  pencolor('red')

pensize(5)
forward(100)
backward(100)
left(Angle)
forward(100)
```

I don't know what is wront with this code.

Comment: `if Angle == '90':` You're comparing an integer to a string.  Integer `90` is not the same as string `"90"`.

Answer (score 0):

`Angle` is an int, but you compare to a string. You have to compare to an int instead:

```
if Angle == 90:
    pencolor('red')
```